# Font Awesome icon direct link

Tags: font-awesome

where can I get the original Font Awesome fa fa icon image link, I use web Developers Tools [Ctrl+Shift+C] and I don't see any link when I click fa fa icons.

> example: fontawesome.com/image/fafa/user-circle-o.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way :

Call Font Awesome in Your Files
Place this code, which contains everything you need, within the  of each template or page that you want to use Font Awesome on.

Ex. -

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 11px;
}
i {
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li><i class="fa fa-download"></i>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```